# Wrong sum count in left join

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting wrong sum count for the query in left join.

These are the 2 separate queries which give correct result individually.

```
SELECT wallpaper_id FROM `contest_participants` WHERE contest_id=2

SELECT wallpaper_id, SUM(upvotes) FROM `contest_wallpaper_upvote` WHERE contest_id=2 GROUP BY wallpaper_id
```

I have used join to sum the upvotes as below

```
Select distinct p.wallpaper_id, sum(u.upvotes) from contest_participants p
Left join contest_wallpaper_upvote as u
On p.wallpaper_id = u.wallpaper_id
Where p.contest_id = 2  group by p.wallpaper_id
```

The problem is if there are no entries for wallpaper_id in upvote table it gives wrong sum count.

Can anybody help me fix the query?

Thanks

Comment: what sum would be correct if there are no upvotes for wallpaper_id?

Comment: It should be 0 if there is no upvote

Comment: use an opposite join, with 0 as default value foir sum if no upvotes present eg https://makandracards.com/makandra/883-mysql-select-a-default-value-for-null-fields

Comment: Can you add the full structure of the tables and some data as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check like below. If the `u.wallpaper_id` is null then you can add `0` otherwise `u.upvotes`

```
Select distinct p.wallpaper_id, sum(if(u.wallpaper_id is null, 0, u.upvotes)) as upvotes from contest_participants p
Left join contest_wallpaper_upvote as u
On p.wallpaper_id = u.wallpaper_id AND u.contest_id = 2
Where p.contest_id = 2  group by p.wallpaper_id
```

Comment: it's giving wrong values. For id that exists in participants table but not in upvote table.

Comment: There is contest table in which there are entries for wallpapers and there is upvote table which adds on entry when someone upvotes wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `distinct`. Does not make sense since you are grouping by `wallpaper_id`. 
And add `contest_id` to `LEFT JOIN` condition.